# JQuery hide() not work on Mozzila but works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, firefox, mozilla

I have a several spans and one of them must be hided depending on conditions:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td>
            <span id="enabled_VALUE_@i">...</span>
            <span id="disabled_VALUE_@i">...</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And somewhere in jquery I have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tpoCount; i++) {
    var enabledVALUE = $('#enabled_VALUE_' + i + '');
    var disabledVALUE = $('#disabled_VALUE_' + i + '');

    ... Action ...

    if (result == 'True') {
        enabledVALUE.hide();
        disabledVALUE.show();
    }
    else {
        enabledVALUE.show();
        disabledVALUE.hide();
    }
}
```

Works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox/Mozzila for some reason **span are never hiding**.

It is strange because at this page **I also have another** `hide()` which works on Firefox/Mozzila. The only difference is that it is not added with `for` help:

```
<tr>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td>
        <span id="enabled_FIX">...</span>
        <span id="disabled_FIX">...</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and in jquery:

```
if (result == 'True') {
    $('#enabled_FIX').hide();
    $('#enabled_FIX').show();
}
else {
    $('#enabled_FIX').show();
    $('#disabled_FIX').hide();
}
```

I can't understand what am I missing. How can I prevent this kind of issue?

Comment: `if (result == 'True') {
    $('#enabled_FIX').hide();
    $('#enabled_FIX').show();
}` Is this a typo, or you are hiding and showing again the same span?

Comment: It is the same span. Sometimes it is hidden, sometimes not...

Answer (score 0):

Try after putting your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Your Code
});
```

Comment: Em... already do this because span supposed to hide when page is oppened.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 
    var enabledVALUE = $('#enabled_VALUE_' + i);
    var disabledVALUE = $('#disabled_VALUE_' + i);

   enabledVALUE.show()
   enabledVALUE.hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
        <td><span id="enabled_VALUE_0">test1</span>
            <span id="disabled_VALUE_0">test2</span></td>
        <td>
            <span id="enabled_VALUE_1">test3</span>
            <span id="disabled_VALUE_1">test4</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: But how it can explain that its work on chrome without any issue?

Comment: Browsers dont have always the same behavior and that's because each browser is made with a different thinking.

Comment: Made an update to the code suggestions. Please run the code snippet and see. I hope that will give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using class instead of id if there are multiple elements with enabledFix and disabledFix as identifiers. Please check this jsfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/asif1/68w0a1rg/1/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //lets show the hidden data and hide the visible data
        disabled($('.enabledFix_' + i + ''));
        enabled($('.disabledFix_' + i + ''));
    }
});

function enabled(ob){
    ob.show();
}

function disabled(ob){
    ob.hide();
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td> <span class="enabledFix_1">John</span></td>
      <td> <span class="disabledFix_2">Doe</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><span class="enabledFix_2">Jane</span></td>
      <td><span class="disabledFix_2">Doe</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.disabledFix{
    display:none;
}
.enabledFix{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Except that hiding <td> is not a option for me.

Comment: Whether you apply the class to a td or a span doesn't really matter. For your purpose I'd use a class instead of id as well.

Comment: I have made changes to the code please check now. You for loop is not efficient hence i have mostly used functions to hide and show instead saving as a var since after the for loop is run the last value of i will be the only one affected.